# setState of entire object loaded from json file | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

*This function is taken from another question here in StackOverflow I've found about loading data from a file, I couldn't find it and to give credits*

```
 function loadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;

    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
      alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
      return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    if (!input) {
      alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    
    else if (!input.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);
    }

    function receivedText(e) {
      let lines = e.target.result;
      var newArr = JSON.parse(lines);
    
      console.log(newArr.text_box);
      var newState ={
            integration_time: newArr.text_box.integration_time_micro_sec, 
            x_axis_resulotion: newArr.text_box.x_axis_resulotion,
            y_axis_resulotion: newArr.text_box.y_axis_resulotion,
            delay_between_pixels_milisec: newArr.text_box.delay_between_pixels_milisec,
            results_directory: newArr.text_box.results_directory,
            config_file_name: ""
      }
      
      console.log(newState);
      alert(newState.integration_time);
      //This pops up the CORRECT data I want to update
      return {newState};
    }
  }
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    integration_time:configData.text_box.integration_time_micro_sec,//configData.integration_time_micro_sec,
    x_axis_resulotion: configData.text_box.x_axis_resulotion,
    y_axis_resulotion:configData.text_box.y_axis_resulotion,
    delay_between_pixels_milisec: configData.text_box.delay_between_pixels_milisec,
    results_directory: configData.text_box.results_directory,
    config_file_name: ""

    // Example for working handle for changing the value of integration_time
    handleIntegrationTimeInput = e => {
        this.setState({integration_time: e.target.value});
    };
    
    handleLoadConfigFile = e =>{
        loadFile();
        alert(this.state.integration_time); 
        //This pops up the OLD data, the new state wasn't assigned to the state...
    }; 
render(){
return(
//my HTML page as JS
            <input name="loadedConfigFile" id = 'fileInput' type="file"/>
            <input 
            name= "loadConfigButton"
            type= "button"
            id = "buttonLoad"
            value= "Load"
            onClick={this.handleLoadConfigFile}/> 

);
 }
}
export default App;
```

Im new in JS, and I might not understand well the state/object properties very well.
It seems that my newState is maybe a local object or something like that in which I cannot assign it to `this.state`.
I've read a lot about `bind()`, and the meaning of `this`, but I got very confused.
**How can I pass and change the `state` according to my .json data?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this - I made `loadFile` return a promise so you can easily get to the return value from `receivedText`, then in the JSX portion we `await` the promise to get the new state, and then call `setState` with the returned state.

```js
    function loadFile() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var input, file, fr;

            if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
                alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
                return;
            }

            input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            if (!input) {
                alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
            } else if (!input.files) {
                alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
            } else if (!input.files[0]) {
                alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
            } else {
                file = input.files[0];
                fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = receivedText;
                fr.readAsText(file);
            }

            function receivedText(e) {
                let lines = e.target.result;
                var newArr = JSON.parse(lines);

                console.log(newArr.text_box);
                var newState = {
                    integration_time: newArr.text_box.integration_time_micro_sec,
                    x_axis_resulotion: newArr.text_box.x_axis_resulotion,
                    y_axis_resulotion: newArr.text_box.y_axis_resulotion,
                    delay_between_pixels_milisec: newArr.text_box.delay_between_pixels_milisec,
                    results_directory: newArr.text_box.results_directory,
                    config_file_name: ""
                }

                console.log(newState);
                alert(newState.integration_time);
                //This pops up the CORRECT data I want to update
                resolve(newState);
            }
        });
    }

    class App extends Component {
        state = {
            integration_time: configData.text_box.integration_time_micro_sec, //configData.integration_time_micro_sec,
            x_axis_resulotion: configData.text_box.x_axis_resulotion,
            y_axis_resulotion: configData.text_box.y_axis_resulotion,
            delay_between_pixels_milisec: configData.text_box.delay_between_pixels_milisec,
            results_directory: configData.text_box.results_directory,
            config_file_name: ""

            // Example for working handle for changing the value of integration_time
            handleIntegrationTimeInput = e => {
                this.setState({
                    integration_time: e.target.value
                });
            };

            handleLoadConfigFile = async (e) => {
                const newState = await loadFile();
                this.setState(newState, () => {
                    alert(this.state.integration_time);
                });
                
                //This pops up the OLD data, the new state wasn't assigned to the state...
            };
            render() {
                return (
                    //my HTML page as JS
                    <input
                      name = "loadedConfigFile"
                      id = 'fileInput'
                      type = "file"
                    />
                    <input
                      name = "loadConfigButton"
                      type = "button"
                      id = "buttonLoad"
                      value = "Load"
                      onClick={this.handleLoadConfigFile}
                    /> 

                );
            }
        }
        export default App;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much dave, it worked exactly as I wanted it to be.